# How can I see the Minecraft user names using NBTEditor?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I find out the usernames if the player section just shows the UUIDs of the players, as seen in the picture below?
Is there any solution for decoding this?

[image: Picture of UUIDs]

Comment: Idk if this helps but if you look at any of the ones without "server_" at the front it has the Microsoft Account ID as `msa`, which I think might be the same as your XUID (not sure though)

Comment: It should also be noted that there would be no direct way to "decode" them, as it is a completely random ID. Let's say my name is "Bob" and my UUID was "29983..." it isn't like there's some converter that converts "Bob" to that UUID. It's a random code that is merely associated with the name in the case of XUIDs. But a UUID is always random and never correlates to a string. You would have to find what is associated with what.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, but it is pretty tedious...
What I did was used scoreboard values, and using the scoreboard ID's to find the players ID's (that way you know like this play has "thismuch'money'" you can think, Oh, So-and-so has that much money!) then go to the players part in MCC, (just click on the subfolder called "players" and a list will come up. Scroll down until you find players that actually have health and hunger, and it will show on one of them the ID that you found with the scoreboard.
Or, if you know whats in their inventories you could look throught those, but thats even more time wastful......

Answer (score 0):

Those codes (I am referring to the text after player_ or player_server_) are the UUIDs (unique identifiers) of the players.

On Bedrock Edition there seems to be no easy way of getting usernames from UUIDs, at least at the time of writing this answer.

On Java Edition, every Minecraft player has a different UUID which is a randomly generated string. This means that players can change their names multiple times easily.

To get the username of a player in Java Edition from the UUID I would recommend using NameMC (https://namemc.com/).

Comment: Why would the Java Edition UUID be needed? This is for bedrock